# Product with image adding on magento2 using curl php. it shows error '{"message":"Specified request cannot be processed."}

Tags: magento2, curl

json data body datas are..

```
"entry": {  
        "id": 0,    
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": "Image",
            "position": 1,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "image",
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail"      ],
            "content": {
                "base64_encoded_data": "'.$productimage.'",
                 "type": "image/png",
                "name": "tshirt.png"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please add endpoint or explain more in detail what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try change param for base_64_encoded_data.
Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#tag/productsskumedia

Comment: changed base64_encoded_data param still getting same error

Comment: Remove id param.
What happens if you send same request via restApi?